# Multiple integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

We know that the double integration is used to find the area of a planer region and volume of a solid object in space.
My question is why we use triple integration to find again the volume a body?
(I know the importance of triple integration, any boddy plz)

Comment: Because triple integration allows us to find the volumes of objects for which double integration is inadequate.  Just like how double integration is used to find areas of regions for which single integration is inadequate.

Comment: @tilper may i have a specific example which shows the imprtance of triple integration?

Comment: Try finding the volume of a sphere using a double integral without resorting to an argument involving symmetry, i.e. try computing the volume without cutting the sphere in half, using a double integral to find the volume of either hemisphere, then doubling the result.

Comment: Areas and volumes are used as a motivation for the study of double and triple integrals, but there are many other aplications in mathematics, physics, egeniering,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double integral works for finding volume of a 3D region only when you can establish that the upper and lower bounds (in the $z$ coordinate) can be defined by functions that only depend on $x$ and $y$.

Given a function $f(x,y)$ and a region $R$ in the $x,y$ plane, the volume of the solid bounded between the surface defined by $f$, the place, and $R$ is
$$\iint_Rf(x,y)\,\mathrm dA$$
For simplicity, let's agree to use a rectangular region for $R$ with $x\in(a,b)$ and $y\in(c,d)$, so that the above can be written
$$\int_c^d\int_a^bf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$
Denote this solid by $S$. This double integral is equivalent to the triple integral
$$\iiint_S\mathrm dV=\int_c^d\int_a^b \int_0^{f(x,y)} 1\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$
But this equivalence only holds if the bounding surface $f$ is an explicit function of the real plane.

The example from my comment challenges you to use a double integral to compute a sphere's volume. Without relying on the symmetry argument I alluded to, this is difficult. A sphere (radius $1$, centered at the origin) is defined by the implicit function $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. There is no way to write $z$ explicitly as the subject of $x$ and $y$. You could use $z=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ as the limits of integration with respect to $z$, but that only works in this case because this particular sphere can be cut perfectly in half along the $x,y$ plane  Not so for more complicated regions, or even a sphere that is translated a little in either vertical direction.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^{f(x,y)} 1\ dz$ should be the inner integral on the RHS.